# Can't send multiple PHP mail() headers in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using `Gravity Forms` to handle forms and after the form submission I have coded a simple mail() function to send an email to the user. The headers work fine individually:

```
$headers = 'From: MyName\r\n';

// or 

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';

mail('me@gmail.com', 'My Subject', 'My Content', $headers);
```

but together in either order there is an issue"

```
$headers = 'From: MyName\r\n'; // works fine
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n'; // In this case the body is not rendered as HTML
// or
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n'; // renders as HTML
$headers .= 'From: MyName\r\n'; // This now gives "unknown sender"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you using Gravity Forms to send notifications? All you have to do is make another notification (i.e. other than admin) and have it send to the email address of the submitter.

Comment: Two reasons (1) Because the email is conditional upon the user checking a checkbox (2) Because Notifications is not finding the form's email address ("Your form does not have an email field. Add an email field to your form and try again.")

Comment: You can use conditional logic for notifications. You should have an email field if you are sending an email confirmation to a user. There is a specific field preset called email.

Comment: @Aibrean, thanks...I will try this. But the question remains: what is wrong with my headers? I just became accustomed to adding these custom functions as 'gform_after_submission' to format things exactly the way I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks need to be double-quoted in order for `"\r\n"` to be respected. As the headers are currently defined, `'\r\n'` is being treated as literal text, not a line break.

```
$headers = "From: MyName\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```